# X Y scatter chart with groups

Tags: crystal-reports

Here's a sample from my table:

```
Energy     Data     Ratio
   1,    1/1/2017,    1
   2,    1/1/2017,    2
   1,    1/2/2017,    1
   2,    1/2/2017,    2
```

I want to group by `Energy` and show the `Date` and `Ratio`.  I've gotten to the point where the chart in the Report Header will show the right grouping in the chart legend, but it only does the first date then stops.  Ie it only shows 1/1/2017, and not subsequent dates.

On change of:  Energy
Show values:
`mIrradDate` (a formula which returns the irrdate date, a trick to enable 'don't summarize')
`mRatio`

How can I show all the data?

Answer (score 1):

Crystal evaluates things top to bottom, and gains data as it goes through the report. So by placing it in the Report Header, it reads one record, prints your chart, then reads the rest of the records. (If you put it in the Report Footer, it'd evaluate after all the data was read, and show all the records.)

You can try any of the following:

- Place the chart in the Report Footer instead
- Evaluate `whileprintingrecords`
- Configure a near-identical subreport that suppresses everything but this scatter plot in the footer. Then place the whole subreport in the header of your main report.

Comment: Thanks , I should have been more clear ,the chart is called from a subreport within the details of the main report.  I tried placing the chart within the report footer (RF) of both the main and subreport, same issue.  It's puzzling.

Comment: @Rob You're using total formulas, right? You're not just straight-up evaluating the fields themselves?

Comment: I'm using a formula which is literally the field  {MYTABLE.MYFIELD} because this is the only way to get the checkbox for summerize results to turn off.